# NFT image not able display in matemask (only grey image)

Tags: solidity, nft, ipfs

I just created a NFT and deployed it on Rinkeby to test it.

I'm able to add my NFTs to wallets but I don't see the image I provided when minted it.

What could be the reason? i ve json and metadata as wel provided with a URI to the contract.
[image]

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x9620ab62A7BD46d1F6308f1461b723039B1CFDc5

contract.sol - point URI to metadata folder (not imeages folder)

```
 _baseTokenURI = "ipfs://QmPaeiDjhrsdAL9PMNyZZgXTwjQp7JPeTF7ntdh2UhoSik/";  //metadata url
```

Able to query ips URL with input tokenID

[image]

[image]

here is my metadata (json) and image file

```
{
    "title": "TigerNFT #1",
    "type": "Collectible",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Identifies the asset to which this NFT represents"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Fortune Tigers Punk"
        },
        "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmNm3JHSGhBgL5D5sBov2kjAtxDKEoC9SF1Rq81Tqt52jp/1145.png"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i am was confuse on this json and uri pointing.

basically i have setup 2 folder

1. images folder
   link *:https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmNm3JHSGhBgL5D5sBov2kjAtxDKEoC9SF1Rq81Tqt52jp*
2. metadata (contain json file)
   link:
   *https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmPaeiDjhrsdAL9PMNyZZgXTwjQp7JPeTF7ntdh2UhoSik*

- in json file point the url to images ***folder link/x.png*** from (1) as below

example:

1.json

```
   "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmNm3JHSGhBgL5D5sBov2kjAtxDKEoC9SF1Rq81Tqt52jp/1145.png"
```

2.json

```
  "image": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmNm3JHSGhBgL5D5sBov2kjAtxDKEoC9SF1Rq81Tqt52jp/4812.png"
    }
}
```

Not sure this is correct setup or not

Comment: Hi appreciate someone can advise me which part gone wrong